# Weird error on codeigniter website - javascript $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, codeigniter

My codeigniter website has a weird error. All echo json_encode statements has a s+carriage return string before the arguments which stops success events from firing due to undefined format and on one page there is also s+carriage return before the html text i send from php. Did any one face such an error before or know where to look or how to correct it?

This is the error output in chrome:

```
<exception>: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
message: "Unexpected token s"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
    at Object.parse (native)
    at e.extend.parseJSON (/js/site/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3:11020)
    at cc (/js/site/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3:1382)
    at w (/js/site/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:7:11263)
    at XMLHttpRequest.f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d (/js/site/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:7:17218)"
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
b: "s

{"status_code":1,"message":"welcome"}"
```

```js
function signin(){

 var signin_email = $('#signin_email_address').val();

 var signin_password = $('#signin_password').val();

 

 

 

  if(signin_email==''){

  alert('Please enter the email address');

 }else if(signin_password==''){

  alert('Please enter the password');

 }else if(signin_password.length < 6){

  alert('Password must be minimum of 6 characters');

 }

 
 else {

  var remember = 'no';

  if($('#remember').is(':checked')){

   remember = 'yes';

  }



  $.ajax({

   

         type: 'POST',

         url: baseURL+'site/user/login_user',

         data: {"email":signin_email,"password":signin_password,"remember":remember

   },

   

         dataType: 'json',

   

         success: function(json){
              

    if(json.status_code == 1){

     window.location.reload();

     

    }else{

    

     alert(json.message);

    }

   }

     });

 }

 return false;

}
```

```html
public function login_user() {
  $returnStr ['status_code'] = 0;
  $returnStr ['message'] = 'welcome';
  //print_r($_POST);die;
  $email = $this->input->post ( 'email' );
  
  $pwd = md5 ( $this->input->post ( 'password' ) );
  
  $bpath = $this->input->post ('bpath');
  
  $remember = $this->input->post ( 'remember' );
  
  if (valid_email($email)) {
   $condition = array (
     'email' => $email,
     'password' => $pwd,
     'status' => 'Active' 
   );
   $checkUser = $this->user_model->get_all_details ( USERS, $condition );
   
   if ($checkUser->num_rows () == '1') {
    $userdata = array (
      'fc_session_user_id' => $checkUser->row ()->id,
      
      'session_user_email' => $checkUser->row ()->email 
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata ( $userdata );
    $datestring = "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s";
    $time = time ();
    $newdata = array (
      'last_login_date' => mdate ( $datestring, $time ),
      'last_login_ip' => $this->input->ip_address () ,
      'login_hit' => 0
    );
    $condition = array (
      'id' => $checkUser->row ()->id 
    );
    $this->user_model->update_details ( USERS, $newdata, $condition );
    if ($remember != '') {
     $userid = $this->encrypt->encode ( $checkUser->row ()->id );
     $cookie = array (
       'name' => 'admin_session',
       'value' => $userid,
       'expire' => 86400,
       'secure' => FALSE 
     );
     $this->input->set_cookie ( $cookie );
    }
    
    $this->setErrorMessage ( 'success', 'You are Logged In ... !' );
    $returnStr ['status_code'] = 1;
   } 
   else
   { 
    $condition = array (
     'email' => $email,
     'status' => 'Active' 
   );
   $checkUser = $this->user_model->get_all_details ( USERS, $condition );
 
   $login_hit = 0;
   if ($checkUser->num_rows () == '1') 
   {
    $login_hit = $checkUser->row()->login_hit;
    $login_hit = $login_hit+1;
    $newdata = array (
      'login_hit' => $login_hit
    );
    $condition = array (
      'id' => $checkUser->row ()->id 
    );
    $this->user_model->update_details ( USERS, $newdata, $condition );
   }
   if($login_hit < 5)
   {
   $returnStr ['message'] = 'Invalid login details';
   }
   else
   {
   $pwd = $this->get_rand_str ( '6' );
   $newdata = array (
    'password' => md5 ( $pwd ) 
   );
   $condition = array (
    'email' => $email 
   );
   $this->user_model->update_details ( USERS, $newdata, $condition );
   $this->send_user_password ( $pwd, $checkUser );
   $this->setErrorMessage ( 'success', 'New password sent to your mail' );
   $returnStr ['message'] = 'New password sent to your email';
   $returnStr ['status_code'] = 1;
   }
   
   }
  } else {
   $returnStr ['message'] = "Invalid email id";
  }
  
        echo json_encode ( $returnStr );
 }
```

Comment: Could you post the code so we can have a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: also post the source output in question

Comment: There has to be something that is echo'ing that s+carriage return. I would check in your index.php or config files for something that should be easy to spot. It would be very difficult / time consuming to upload all your files here so just search for echo or print (or whatever you fav way to outputting data).